# Употребление тире

Tags: пунктуация

Споткнулась на ровном месте. Я думаю — все впереди. Или: Я думаю, все впереди. Изначально было вообще без всяких знаков.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оба варианта возможны.

Здесь "я думаю" можно считать вводным предложением, или это БСП с изъяснительным значением, но без предупредительной паузы, характерной для двоеточия.